# How to stop the leakage from the design?

Tags: seals

I have the design attached. it is like a water cap design. I want to rotate the lid clockwise to seal the circle container. However, I noticed that when I shake the container, water leaks. Note, the lid rotates from the inside of the container, unlike most water bottles.

How can I guarantee sealing it with no leakage? should make the lid rotate from the outside? or is there a quick fix to my design?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think you might have tunnel vision after spending so much time designing the container. The solution is quite obvious, simple, and fast.

When the cap is female, you have a soft, deformable pad at the base inside the cap.

When the cap is male, as it is in your case, a gasket or O-ring is what is used.

Comment: Will the gasket be placed on top of the bottom part? from outside!

Comment: The gasket/O-ring goes around the male thread. I assume you don't want anything in the female thread since that is your container. and would also require the male thread to reach the bottom of the container to be of any use.

Comment: Do they sell gaskets in standard size or can I form mine? because my dimensions might not be standard!

Comment: @AnwarElhadad They gaskets and O-rings in a bunch of different sizes. You can also buy sheet and cut your own. You just have to know the right store. Some places that sells hoses and stuff. If this is for food, get food-grade material which will probably need to be ordered since those stores are mostly for industrial stuff, but industrial stuff includes food processing too sometimes.